# Disable popups on cancelled Sprint service on LG G2

Tags: lg-g2, sprint

I have an LG G2, and recently got a cell phone provided for by my place of work, so I cancelled my Sprint service.

I want to use the phone as a gaming device for my kids, but I keep getting error messages popping up regarding the fact that it cannot connect to the sprint network.

> LTE : ESM-0 EMM-19
>   EHRPD : 5
>   MIP : 67

They pop up very frequently, and I cannot find a way to disable them.

**TL;DR:** Is there a way to disable the popup error messages related to no service on a Sprint LG G2?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the error message and making it go away. But you could always put the device into airplane mode and still use WiFi. That should stop the device from trying to connect to the Sprint towers.

Answer (score -1):

You can root your device and then manually disable those popup settings by editing databases using SQLite editor app.

Some manufacturers put their custom apps as ordered by service providers. Theses apps do not have their own UI, but used by other service provider specific apps to get updated values from service provider as per customer-plan.

These apps change default values of certain actions, responses, service access in SQLite databases that are present in Android devices or build their databases which are accessed by Android system.

By using SQLite editor app, user can browse these databases manually and change values that seems to be connected with this pop-up issue. To browse these databases, device needs root access.

Comment: How is that link helpful? Also, what kind of databases are you talking about? Please see [answer] and give us detailed steps. Thanks!

Comment: @Firelord Link used to be in a forum that gives some woking solutions for related issues as described but not working anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still too vague. Without specific app & database location, this answer is too general and probably won't help much.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue. I removed the SIM card and restarted and have not seen the error message since.the phone still works fine and connects to wifi easily. 
good luck I hope this helps you as well...

Answer (score -1):

Turn off mobile data, this will fix your issue.